# Containerized Laravel application that connects to a remote database

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, github-actions

Good day everyone, I have a Laravel application that is supposed to connect to a remote MYSQL database in production, and to ease deployment I am using docker. I have setup a GitHub actions workflow that is triggered when I push to master branch, the workflow essentially runs a couple of tests and then builds my app into an image and then pushes to docker hub.
To avoid database connection issues when ***composer dump-autoload*** is run during the build process, I allowed connection from any host (***changed bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in mysql config***) and also setup the mysql user to connect from any host. This seems to do the trick but my concern is obviously exposing my database service to the entire world. Fortunately its possible to setup my own dedicated server for Github actions, which means I can easily restrict my db service to that host. Would that be the Ideal solution or there is way to run the workflow without needing to connect to a database?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to remote database using an SSH Tunnel

```
ssh -N -L 3336:127.0.0.1:3306 [USER]@[REMOTE_SERVER_IP]
```

With this you do not need to publish MySQL to the world and could bind it to 127.0.0.1 on Remote host.